# jQuery: How to get the dynamic height of header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery. And I can't figure out the solution to this problem.

So, the problem is that I want a fixed header on my website. I did that with CSS. But I want to give the main container div(right below the header) a margin-top of the height of the header.

For example, if the `#masthead` (header) height is `100px`, I want to give a margin-top of `100px` to `.site-container`.

I can easily do it with CSS, but due to some reason, there will be different header height on different pages. Or let's suppose that I don't know the height of the header.

So I want to do it using jQuery.

Here is the code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var header = document.getElementById("masthead");

  var header_height = header.offsetHeight + "px";

  $( '.site-content' ).css( {
          'margin-top': header_height
  } );

});
```

It works perfectly. But there is just one problem.

That, the header height on my website changes in different screen size. In Desktop Screen size, the `#masthead` height is `80px`, in tablet, the screen size is `160px` and in mobile, it's `60px`.

But, the value of header height does not change with the change in screen size in jQuery.

In jQuery, I want the value of the variable `header` to change dynamically, with the change in screen size.

Please note that I am working on a WordPress website.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, I would not do it with scripting, but with layout. create one main div with position relative. inside, put two position relative divs, one for your header, and second one for your all other content. then, as your header will have whatever height, the content div will be right below it.

Comment: @Zorak I agree! A lot of scripting problems are truly layout problem. However, this might be a `position: absolute` menu.

Comment: I need the header to be fixed at top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

- Use a window resize function

**You could also use**: (to make your life easier :)

- [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)
- [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to "Get the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin)"

**Example code**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     // When the window resizes
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
         // Get the height + padding + border of `#masthead`
         var mastHeight = $('#masthead').outerHeight();

        // Add the height to `.site-content`
        $('.site-content').css('margin-top', mastHeight); 
    });

     // Trigger the function on document load.
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the same function on window.resize.

By the way, after resize the screen reload the page, hope your code will work as it will get the  document ready function.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the same function on both page load and window resize.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function resizeContent(){
  var header = document.getElementById("masthead");
  var header_height = header.offsetHeight + "px";
  $( '.site-content' ).css( {
          'margin-top': header_height
  });
  }
  resizeContent();
  $(window).resize(resizeContent);
});
```